# Convert NSDictionary to NSString in a predefined format and convert back

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to convert NSDictionary into string format in a predefined format and then convert back to the original dictionary. The string has to be in a pre defined format. such as:

What I did is very tedious:

Convert dictionary to string:

```
+ (NSString *)cipherTextWithMessage:(Message *)message {
    NSString *entity = @"Message";
    NSString *entityID = message.entityID;
    NSString *roomID = message.room.entityID;
    NSString *userID = message.sender.userID;
    NSString *datetime = [[self private_dateFormatter] stringFromDate:message.datetime];
    NSNumber *selfDestructive = message.selfDestructive;
    NSString *status = message.status;
    NSString *type = message.type;
    NSString *originalBlobID = message.originalBlobID;
    NSString *thumbnailBlobID = message.thumbnailBlobID;
    NSString *text = message.text;
    NSString *posx = [Format posStringWithNumber:message.posx];
    NSString *posy = [Format posStringWithNumber:message.posy];
    NSString *link = message.link;

    NSString *plainText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"entity=%@ entityID=%@ roomID=%@ userID=%@ datetime=%@ selfDestructive=%@ status=%@ type=%@ originalBlobID=%@ thumbnailBlobID=%@ posx=%@ posy=%@ link=%@ text=%@", entity, entityID, roomID, userID, datetime, selfDestructive, status, type, originalBlobID, thumbnailBlobID, posx, posy, link, text];
    return [self private_encrypt:plainText];
}
```

convert string to dictionary

```
+ (NSMutableDictionary *)infoWithCipherText:(NSString *)cipherText {
    NSString *plainText = [self private_decrypt:cipherText];

    if ([plainText hasPrefix:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"entity=%@", @"Message"]]) {

        NSArray *array = [plainText componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        NSString *entity = [((NSString *)array[0]) substringFromIndex:@"entity=".length];
        NSString *entityID = [((NSString *)array[1]) substringFromIndex:@"entityID=".length];
        NSString *roomID = [((NSString *)array[2]) substringFromIndex:@"roomID=".length];
        NSString *userID = [((NSString *)array[3]) substringFromIndex:@"userID=".length];
        NSString *datetime = [((NSString *)array[4]) substringFromIndex:@"datetime=".length];
        NSString *selfDestructive = [((NSString *)array[5]) substringFromIndex:@"selfDestructive=".length];
        NSString *status = [((NSString *)array[6]) substringFromIndex:@"status=".length];
        NSString *type = [((NSString *)array[7]) substringFromIndex:@"type=".length];
        NSString *originalBlobID = [((NSString *)array[8]) substringFromIndex:@"originalBlobID=".length];
        NSString *thumbnailBlobID = [((NSString *)array[9]) substringFromIndex:@"thumbnailBlobID=".length];


        NSString *posx = [((NSString *)array[10]) substringFromIndex:@"posx=".length];
        NSString *posy = [((NSString *)array[11]) substringFromIndex:@"posy=".length];
        NSString *link = [((NSString *)array[12]) substringFromIndex:@"link=".length];


        NSString *pref = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"entity=%@ entityID=%@ roomID=%@ userID=%@ datetime=%@ selfDestructive=%@ status=%@ type=%@ originalBlobID=%@ thumbnailBlobID=%@ posx=%@ posy=%@ link=%@ text=", entity, entityID, roomID, userID, datetime, selfDestructive, status, type, originalBlobID, thumbnailBlobID, posx, posy, link];
        NSString *text = [plainText substringFromIndex:pref.length];

        NSMutableDictionary *info = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        info[@"entity"] = entity;
        info[@"entityID"] = entityID;
        info[@"roomID"] = roomID;
        info[@"userID"] = userID;
        info[@"datetime"] = [[self private_dateFormatter] dateFromString:datetime];
        info[@"selfDestructive"] = [NSNumber numberWithBool:selfDestructive.boolValue];
        info[@"status"] = status;
        info[@"type"] = type;
        info[@"originalBlobID"] = originalBlobID;
        info[@"thumbnailBlobID"] = thumbnailBlobID;
        info[@"posx"] = [Format posWithPosString:posx];
        info[@"posy"] = [Format posWithPosString:posy];
        info[@"link"] = link;
        info[@"text"] = text;
        return info;
    }
}
```

1. for the first function, I probably will write into `dictionary[@"entityID"] = message.entityID` instead. so this is still converting dictionary to string problem.
2. I don't want to write this for all my entities, is there any easy way to do it?
3. the last attribute is 'text' and it can contain any characters including '=' and blank. that's why i put it at the end and construct the 'prefix string. but it's very tedious.
4. the order does not matter. but it would be good if it's in alphabetical order.

Comment: Seems to me you should simply use iteration to build the desired result. There is no need to hardcode everything.

Comment: Either use JSON or use the NSDictionary file operations to write/read a property list format.  JSON will (within reason) interchange with other languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear what you are ultimately trying to do, but it seems to me that you might be over-thinking this. What I would do here is convert the dictionary directly to a plist - because this feature is built right in (for example, it is what `writeToFile:` does). You could write to a file and read the file as an NSString, and presto, you've got an XML version of your dictionary.

Alternatively, if you call `NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:`, you can convert your dictionary to an NSData in a single step, suitable for encrypting and sending to another machine

Either way, reversing the process is equally trivial.

Comment: no the format has to be that one ('key1'='value1' 'key2'='value2'... and the last key is 'text'. and I don't write to files. I send the string to server

Comment: And the server can't read/interpret XML? Or you could convert the XML to JSON and send that.

Comment: yes but i decided the web api months ago and i have done tons of coding for it, if i change it to json or xml i have to delete them

Comment: So you've created a bad spec and now you're complaining because your spec is bad.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

Dictionary to string:

```
NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString string];
NSDictionary *dict = ... // your dictionary
for (NSString *key in [dict allKeys]) {
    id value = dict[key];
    if (result.length) {
        [result appendString:@" "];
    }
    [result appendFormat:@"%@=%@", key, [value description]];
}

// result has the desired string
```

String to dictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSString *text = ... // the string created from the above
NSArray *array = [plainText componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
for (NSString *pair in array) {
    NSArray *parts = [pair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
    dict[parts[0]] = parts[1];
}
// dict is now populated with the keys and values
```

Comment: is it possible to order the keys?

Comment: Of course. Get the array of keys and use one of the many ways to sort that array. Then use the sorted array in the `for` loop.

Comment: the last attribute is 'text' and it contains any string including '=' and blank. do I have to do this?         NSString *pref = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"entity=%@ entityID..... etc?

Answer (score 0):

Your  "**Convert dictionary to string**"  block have no dictionary, so I don't know how to help you as your message object can be every things...

You can use for your "**string to dictionary**" conversion :

```
+ (NSMutableDictionary *)infoWithCipherText:(NSString *)cipherText {
    NSString *plainText = [self private_decrypt:cipherText];

    if ([plainText hasPrefix:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"entity=%@", @"Message"]]) {

        NSArray *array = [plainText componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

        NSMutableDictionary *info = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        for (NSString *keyvalString in array) {
            NSArray *keyvalArray = [keyvalString componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
            if ([keyvalArray count] == 2) {
                info[[keyvalArray firstObject]] = [keyvalArray lastObject];
            }
        }

       return info;
    } else {
       return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: for the first function, I probably will write into `dictionary[@"entityID"] = message.entityID` instead. so this is still converting dictionary to string problem